# Derivative formula for billinear function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I am reading Spivaks "Calculus on Manifolds" and I am unable to see how the formula below follows given the formula below it

> $$Df(a_1,...,a_k)(x_1,...,x_k)=\sum_{i=1}^kf(a_1,...,a_{i-1},x_i,a_{i+1},...,a_k)$$

This formula applies when $f$ is billinear

> $$Df(a,b)(x,y)=f(a,y)+f(x,b)$$

I think it would help me to see a few terms expanded from the sum in the first equation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thats because$$f(a+x,b+y)-f(a,b)-f(a,y)-f(x,b)=f(x,y)$$and therefore$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\bigl\|f(a+x,b+y)-f(a,b)-f(a,y)-f(x,b)\bigr\|}{\bigl\|(x,y)\|}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\bigl\|f(x,y)\bigr\|}{\bigl\|(x,y)\|}=0.$$

---

General case:\begin{multline}f(a_1+x_1,\ldots,a_k+x_k)-f(a_1,\ldots,a_k)-\sum_{j=1}^kf(a_1,...,a_{j-1},x_j,a_{j+1},...,a_k)=\\=f(x_1,\ldots,x_k)\end{multline}and therefore\begin{multline}\lim_{(x_1,\ldots,x_k)\to(0,\ldots,0)}\frac{\left\|f(a_1+x_1,\ldots,a_k+x_k)-f(a_1,\ldots,a_k)-\sum_{j=1}^kf(a_1,...,a_{j-1},x_j,a_{j+1},...,a_k)\right\|}{\|(x_1,\ldots,x_k)\|}=\\=\lim_{(x_1,\ldots,x_k)\to(0,\ldots,0)}\frac{\left\|f(x_1,\ldots,x_k)\right\|}{\|(x_1,\ldots,x_k)\|}=0.\end{multline}

Comment: I get the proof for the second formula I wrote.  What I was asking was how $\sum_{i=1}^kf(a_1,...,a_{i-1},x_i,a_{i+1},...,a_k)$ relates to $f(a,y)+f(x,b)$.  In the bilinear case I can sort of memorize that I need to pair $(a,y)$ then $(x,b)$.  But what's going in the multinear case?  What's the pattern? Thanks again

Comment: @johnfowles I've edited my answer. What do you think now?